# Extract a GFS variable

Tags: meteorology

I'm trying to extract the APCP variable from a GFS file, with this code:

```
wgrib2 gfst.grb2 -match ":(APCP):"  - grib gfst.grb2.small
```

I get a

```
FATAL ERROR: too many grib files .. 1st=gfst.grb2 2nd=-
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand upon my comments:

[This page from CPC](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/problems.html) suggests that the error message is likely due to wgrib2 thinking subsequent arguments are actually additional grib files because they aren't properly given the **-** prefix.  That lead me to realize that you have a space between your last dash and grib which appears to cause the error:

> wgrib2 gfst.grb2 -match ":(APCP):" - grib gfst.grb2.small

should be

> wgrib2 gfst.grb2 -match ":(APCP):" **-grib** gfst.grb2.small

Hopefully that helps if anyone else comes across the issue at a later date!  You might also have forgotten a dash somewhere... or tried using too many arguments in an option?